# Is it possible to do a color overlay on a specific section of an image in WordPress/Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, colors

Let's say I have a product - a girl's dress which has three colors. Top, middle and bottom sections of the dress are n different colors. Is it possible to create an option for this, that a client could pick up provided colors and he would be able to change those colors whichever way he wants? Let's say he wants to see how the dress would look with green/yellow/blue variation or maybe opposite way. Sorry if this is too confusing:)

Comment: Is there any documentation in the Woocommerce plugins that could help with this?

Comment: Nah... Could not find plugins that perform such task..

Answer (score 0):

The Woocommerce Composite Product plugin has this functionality: https://woocommerce.com/products/composite-products/

You just need to use the (free) Conditional Images extension for the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/composite-products-conditional-images-for-woocommerce/

For a live demo of the possibilities, see my website: https://www.bristolbicycles.co.uk/products/hybrid-bike
(as you select different components, the picture of the bike changes).

You could do the same for different colours (or shapes or styles) on the dress.